# Impossible: UPDATE statement fails while SELECT succeeds

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, ssms

How is it possible, that this query runs successfully:

```
SELECT ClientIp, LEFT(clientip, CHARINDEX(',', clientip) - 1)
FROM tblIISLog
WHERE clientip LIKE '%,%';
```

but this update statement throws the error below:

```
UPDATE tblIISLog
  SET ClientIp = LEFT(clientip, CHARINDEX(',', clientip) - 1)
WHERE clientip LIKE '%,%';
```

```
Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 6
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.
The statement has been terminated.
```

It is the exact same table and where clause, and no rows have been added in between. This should not happen, unless SQL server somehow calculates the LEFT for more rows than expected.
Can someone explain this?

EDIT:
A workaround is provided below already, but as to answer the WHY. This is the query plan for the UPDATE:

[image]

And this for the SELECT:

[image]

The compute-scalar step, is actually executed BEFORE the filter step, which is why the expression could come accross ClientIp rows without any ','.

Comment: Are there any null, or zero length values in the ClientIp field?

Comment: Can you create and post a [mre]?

Comment: You cannot be sure that SQL server will apply the filter before handling other parts of the query, depending on the query plan. You need to make sure that CHARINDEX() -1 does not become a negative value.

Comment: @nire If there are, they are ignored by the same WHERE clause as the SELECT statement. So i would expect errors for both statement, or none at all

Comment: SQL Server isn't compelled, nor should be expected to, use the same execution plan for (very) similar queries, @Kevin . In fact, it can use a different query plan for the *same* query at a later date should it feel so because there's a better option (perhaps due to new indexes).

Comment: @Kevin '%,%' is a match if the value is ','. Since you are selecting anything with a comma (or just a comma) and therefore CHARINDEX could return 1. The result of 1 - 1 is 0.

To be sure, you could do a select and add the where clause: where (CHARINDEX(',', clientip) - 1) < 1

Comment: @Nire but SELECT LEFT('abc',0) is valid and just returns an empty varchar. So the problem is really with rows that do not contain any comma, which would result in 0-1 = -1, and that is not a valid param for the LEFT expression. As Larnu explains, this is all up to the query engine, and i therefore cannot simply assume my WHERE clause has filtered all data before the LEFT expression is executed ;)

Comment: You should really add your answer as an answer, rather than an edit to your question.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't answer the *why* one works and the other doesn't, though the comments touch on it and that is due to in the query plan perhaps the expression in the `SET` is being derived before the `WHERE` (this can happen). Perhaps we have an overly simplified query in the above, and that is why we can't see an obvious reason.

As for avoiding it, however, one method would be to use `NULLIF`:

```sql
UPDATE tblIISLog
  SET ClientIp = LEFT(clientip, NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', clientip),0) - 1)
WHERE clientip LIKE '%,%';
```

This will mean that the expression will resolve to `NULL` is there is no `,` in the string.

Comment: That does the job! I can't wrap my mind around it, why SQL would try to run the expression though for rows not included. That seems very inefficient to me, but as you mentioned, is something probably deep in the engine, and needed for other reasons...

Comment: It's why I asked for a [mre], @Kevin . We can't run your SQL, and my rudimentary attempts to replicate your problem failed.

Comment: I understand @Larnu, the question cannot really be answered without it. I cannot provide a minimum reproducible example though because i don't know what is causing it. This only makes me realize i don't know half of what is going on beneath the surface. Maybe it is caused by the ClusteredColumnstoreIndex on this table, or statistics are wrong. With your work around i was able to run the update, so i'll leave it at that :)

Comment: I've added the queryplans to the post. I think that explains where the error comes from.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, to avoid passing a negative value to the left function:

```
UPDATE tblIISLog
  SET ClientIp = LEFT(clientip, nullif(CHARINDEX(',', clientip), 0) - 1)
WHERE clientip LIKE '%,%';
```